# Error with smarty ( Syntax Error in template )

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

Error appears on page , I use smarty for template

Error smarty is:

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message
 'Syntax Error in template &quot;.\templates\footer.tpl&quot; 
on line 72 &quot;var reg = /^(([^&amp;lt;&amp;gt;()[\]\\.,;:\s@\&amp;quot;]+(\.[^&amp;lt;&amp;gt;()[\]\\.,;:\s@\&amp;quot;]+)*)|(\&amp;quot;.+\&amp;quot;))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;&quot;
```

Line 72 is ( js ) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateEmail(email) { 
        var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return reg.test(email);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [{literal}](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal.tpl) tag to escape these parts that may conflict.

I quote:

> {literal}
>
> {literal} tags allow a block of data to be taken literally. This is
>   typically used around Javascript or stylesheet blocks where {curly
>   braces} would interfere with the template delimiter syntax. Anything
>   within {literal}{/literal} tags is not interpreted, but displayed
>   as-is. If you need template tags embedded in a {literal} block,
>   consider using {ldelim}{rdelim} to escape the individual delimiters
>   instead.